# output need to achieve by one query

Tags: sql, oracle, count, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have table which consist data like below.

```
Tran_id      status
abc            d
xyz            f
mnp            d
klm            s 
anz            f
```

I need output in pivot :

```
Total No Of d: 2
Total No Of f: 2
Total No. Of s: 1
Total no Of Status : 5
```

I can achieve by separate queries easily but is it possible to get it done by one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation such as

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN status='d' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Total # Of D",
       SUM(CASE WHEN status='f' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Total # Of F",
       SUM(CASE WHEN status='s' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Total # Of S",
       COUNT(*) AS "Total # Of Status"
  FROM tab
```

in order to return results pivoted.

Answer (score 2):

You are not describing a pivot, but an aggregation query, with a rollup. That would look like:

```
select status, count(*) as cnt
from mytable
group by rollup (status)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use grouping sets clause within group by clause to make your own group by subset like below

```sql
select 'Total No Of '||nvl(to_char(status), 'Status') ||': '|| count(*)
from your_tab
group by grouping sets (status, ())
;
```